# how to save results to Excel file or csv files?

Tags: java, database, csv

I'm using the following code to extract some data and save them to CSV file. But the problem now is that the program writes the data into the CSV file and whenever the code runs again, that gets deleted and the old results will be replaced with the new ones! 
The question is, is there any way to save the results and store the new results in a new row? if yes then how to do that?

here is my code:

```
 private void writeReport() {
    BufferedWriter out = null;
   try {
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.csv");
        out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write("File Name;");
        out.write("Total Lines of Code;");
        out.write("Executable Lines;");
        out.write("Lines of Comments;");
        out.write("Trivial Lines;");
        out.write("Empty Lines;");
        out.write("Code Complexity;");
        out.write("Number of Files;"); //to be changed to numver of files 
        out.write("Average File Complexity;"); //to be changed to averag file complexity
        out.write("Comment Percentage;"); //total
        out.write("Total Lines of Test Code;");
        out.write("Total Comments in Tests;");
        out.write("Total Trivial Lines in Tests;");
        out.write("Total Empty Lines in Tests;");
        out.write("Total Number of Test Files;");
        out.write("Comment Presentage in Test;");

        out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

      //  for (int i = 0; i < newFiles.getNrOfFiles(); i++) {
            out.write("test" + ";");
        //    out.write(newFiles.getParser(i).getSourceFile().getName()+ ";");
            out.write(String.valueOf(newFiles.sumLinesOfCode()) + ";");
            out.write(String.valueOf(newFiles.sumLinesOfStatements()) + ";");
            out.write(String.valueOf(newFiles.sumLinesOfComments()) + ";");
            out.write(String.valueOf(newFiles.sumTrivialLines()) + ";");
            out.write(String.valueOf(newFiles.sumEmptyLines()) + ";");
            out.write(String.valueOf(newFiles.sumComplexity())+ ";");
            out.write(String.valueOf(newFiles.getNrOfFiles()) + ";");
            out.write(String.valueOf(newFiles.sumAvgComplexity()) + ";");
            out.write(String.valueOf((100 * newFiles.sumLinesOfComments()) / newFiles.sumLinesOfCode() + "%") + ";");

            out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        //Close the output stream
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      //  return;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `new FileWriter("out.csv", true);` which will append to the current file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine if the file already exists

```
File file = new File("out.csv");
boolean exists = file.exists();
```

and then open the writer in append mode if file exists

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file, exists /*=append*/);
```

and write your headers only when the file did not exist yet.

```
if (!exists) {
    out.write("File Name;");
    ...
    out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
// write new rows
```

Also some things get easier when you use a `PrintWriter`:

```
PrintWriter out;
...
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(fstream));
...
out.println(); // easier than out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: Great idea specially with the boolean for the headers, but now its jumping a row each time it runs, so the headers are being written ones ( which is perfect ) but its escaping ( jumping ) a row each time it runs. so if it has written at row 2 the next running time its writing on 4 and then on 6, how can i make it so it write row after another?
thanks

Comment: @user5923402 when you write the newline after the headers this must also be done within the block of the `if (!exists)` - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org).

Here is some example code (excerpted and adapted from org.apache.poi.hssf.dev.HSSF test class):
short rownum;

```
// create a new file
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
// create a new workbook
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
// create a new sheet
Sheet s = wb.createSheet();
// declare a row object reference
Row r = null;
// declare a cell object reference
Cell c = null;
// create 3 cell styles
CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
CellStyle cs2 = wb.createCellStyle();
CellStyle cs3 = wb.createCellStyle();
DataFormat df = wb.createDataFormat();
// create 2 fonts objects
Font f = wb.createFont();
Font f2 = wb.createFont();

//set font 1 to 12 point type
f.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 12);
//make it blue
f.setColor( (short)0xc );
// make it bold
//arial is the default font
f.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

//set font 2 to 10 point type
f2.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 10);
//make it red
f2.setColor( (short)Font.COLOR_RED );
//make it bold
f2.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);

f2.setStrikeout( true );

//set cell stlye
cs.setFont(f);
//set the cell format 
cs.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("#,##0.0"));

//set a thin border
cs2.setBorderBottom(cs2.BORDER_THIN);
//fill w fg fill color
cs2.setFillPattern((short) CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
//set the cell format to text see DataFormat for a full list
cs2.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("text"));

// set the font
cs2.setFont(f2);

// set the sheet name in Unicode
wb.setSheetName(0, "\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043E\u0432\u0430\u044F " + 
                   "\u0421\u0442\u0440\u0430\u043D\u0438\u0447\u043A\u0430" );
// in case of plain ascii
// wb.setSheetName(0, "HSSF Test");
// create a sheet with 30 rows (0-29)
int rownum;
for (rownum = (short) 0; rownum < 30; rownum++)
{
    // create a row
    r = s.createRow(rownum);
    // on every other row
    if ((rownum % 2) == 0)
    {
        // make the row height bigger  (in twips - 1/20 of a point)
        r.setHeight((short) 0x249);
    }

    //r.setRowNum(( short ) rownum);
    // create 10 cells (0-9) (the += 2 becomes apparent later
    for (short cellnum = (short) 0; cellnum < 10; cellnum += 2)
    {
        // create a numeric cell
        c = r.createCell(cellnum);
        // do some goofy math to demonstrate decimals
        c.setCellValue(rownum * 10000 + cellnum
                + (((double) rownum / 1000)
                + ((double) cellnum / 10000)));

        String cellValue;

        // create a string cell (see why += 2 in the
        c = r.createCell((short) (cellnum + 1));

        // on every other row
        if ((rownum % 2) == 0)
        {
            // set this cell to the first cell style we defined
            c.setCellStyle(cs);
            // set the cell's string value to "Test"
            c.setCellValue( "Test" );
        }
        else
        {
            c.setCellStyle(cs2);
            // set the cell's string value to "\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442"
            c.setCellValue( "\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442" );
        }


        // make this column a bit wider
        s.setColumnWidth((short) (cellnum + 1), (short) ((50 * 8) / ((double) 1 / 20)));
    }
}

//draw a thick black border on the row at the bottom using BLANKS
// advance 2 rows
rownum++;
rownum++;

r = s.createRow(rownum);

// define the third style to be the default
// except with a thick black border at the bottom
cs3.setBorderBottom(cs3.BORDER_THICK);

//create 50 cells
for (short cellnum = (short) 0; cellnum < 50; cellnum++)
{
    //create a blank type cell (no value)
    c = r.createCell(cellnum);
    // set it to the thick black border style
    c.setCellStyle(cs3);
}

//end draw thick black border


// demonstrate adding/naming and deleting a sheet
// create a sheet, set its title then delete it
s = wb.createSheet();
wb.setSheetName(1, "DeletedSheet");
wb.removeSheetAt(1);
//end deleted sheet

// write the workbook to the output stream
// close our file.  (don't blow out our file handles
wb.write(out);
out.close();
```

**Reading or modifying an existing file**

Reading in a file is equally simple. To read in a file, create a new instance of `org.apache.poi.poifs.Filesystem`, passing in an open `InputStream`, such as a `FileInputStream` for your XLS, to the constructor. Construct a new instance of `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook` passing the Filesystem instance to the constructor. From there you have access to all of the high level model objects through their assessor methods `(workbook.getSheet(sheetNum)`, `sheet.getRow(rownum), etc)`.

Modifying the file you have read in is simple. You retrieve the object via an assessor method, remove it via a parent object's remove method `(sheet.removeRow(hssfrow))` and create objects just as you would if creating a new xls. When you are done modifying cells just call `workbook.write(outputstream)` just as you did above.

An example of this can be seen in [`org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.examples.HSSFRead`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/examples/HSSFReadWrite.java)

Answer (score 1):

The FileWriter class has another constructor that takes a boolean that determines whether or not to append to the existing file.

```
FileWriter(File file, boolean append)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

```
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), '\t');
     // feed in your array (or convert your data to an array)
     String[] entries = "first#second#third".split("#");
     writer.writeNext(entries);
     writer.close();
```

Get it using Maven or Gradle: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv or download and include it in your project manually.